# Result from Support Vector Machine confusing

Tags: python, numpy, svm, miniconda

Hi here is the code image for prediction value ,but i cannot understand about the result... using SVM technique...

[image]

and here is the result for my code

[image]

and here is the data..

[image]

i cannot understand the result  of my code.... please guys will you help me out ...

Answer (score 0):

The result is pretty trivial. You are looking at accuracy on your **training set**, and you are using SVM with rbf kernel, which can overfit to any dataset, and it does so perfectly - it simply remembers all your training points, thus produces perfect predictions on training points. This is not the way you are supposed to do evaluation, you need train-test splits (for problem of that size - many of them, probably strenghtened by cross-validation).

Comment: thanks mate for your comments ...  @lejlot  .. will you please understand me the code....

Comment: I do not understand your comment

Comment: dear mate i want to know about the precision,recall,f1 score and support based on my code ... thanks for your reply @lejjot

Comment: As said in the answer, you need to split your data, probably in cross validation fashion and report these measures on test set (data which is not used for training). Rest of your approach is fine

Comment: dear lejjot will you please give me a cross validation sample code regarding this code ... i need to do that for my thesis ...